# How to clear a specific amount of items from inventory in Minecraft 1.15.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've seen this question answered in many ways but not for 1.15. I want to be able to clear a certain amount of items (let's say 45 stone) from a players inventory. How do I make it so the command only takes 45 stone, no more, no less? Basically, I don't want the command to work if the player doesn't have at least 45 stone in their inventory, and even then, it will only take away 45.

Comment: Hi Pixel, welcome to Arqade! If you linked solutions from other versions of Minecraft that you've found, that would be super helpful for the community to get an answer specific to 1.15.

Comment: 1.15 commands are the same as 1.13 and 1.14 commands in most ways.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! Basically all the answers I found talked about using the /testfor command or the /stats command, which were all removed. I understand that 1.13 and 1.14 have the same command, but I can't find answers for those either.

Comment: @Pixel Yeah, I just encountered that issue as well, it's really annoying. But I found an up-to-date answer anyway. I could have sworn that I even answered one myself, but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: Yeah, I thought I had a 1.13+ answer as well, but it might just be the 1.8/1.9 answer I was thinking of.

Answer (score -1):

/clear playername  minecraft:stone 45

Comment: But that will still clear the items, even if there are less than 45